# Hdparm - Checking if a drive is spun down

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hdparm, spinup

Is there anyway to find out if a hard drive has spun down? I've been using the following command to spin it down after idle time:

```
hdparm -S 120 /dev/hdX
```

However I'm not sure it's working correctly and was wondering how to check the current power state to see if has correctly powered down.

Answer (score 33):

You can find out the power status with the `-C` flag to `hdparm`:

```
hdparm -C /dev/hdX
```

As explained by `man 8 hdparm`:

> -C
>
> Check the current IDE power mode status, which will always
>   be one of unknown  (drive  does  not 
>   support
>                 this  command), active/idle (normal operation),
>   standby (low power mode, drive has
>   spun down), or sleep‐
>                 ing (lowest power mode, drive is completely shut down).  The
>   -S, -y, -Y, and -Z flags  can  be  used  to
>                 manipulate the IDE power modes.

Comment: Caution: many people report that `hdparm -C` wakes up the drive and recommend using `smartctl -i -n standby` instead. (see http://serverfault.com/questions/275364/get-drive-power-state-without-waking-it-up or http://serverfault.com/questions/204227/when-hdd-wakes-up)

Comment: In testing *BOTH* `hdparm -C` and `smartclt -i -n standby` (Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS)

Comment: Are there any "new and improved" solutions? Ideally, something which doesn't require superuser privileges?

Comment: I have a drive that is awaked from spleep both  by hdparm and smartcl commands. And another one that is not awaked by neither.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have `hdparm` nor `smartctl` available on my NAS I checked the `/proc` as I assumed that it had to be there somewhere, too.

Well, if it's down:

```
root@NAS:~# cat /proc/d_suspdtime
SuspendingTime = 15
Disk0: STANDBY
Disk1: No_Disk
root@NAS:~#
```

If the kitten would go crazy on it:

```
root@NAS:~# cat /proc/d_suspdtime
SuspendingTime = 15
Disk0: ACTIVE
Disk1: No_Disk
root@NAS:~#
```

I also got

```
root@NAS:/proc# cat /proc/d_suspdtime
SuspendingTime = 15
Disk0: NO_ACTIVE
Disk1: No_Disk
root@NAS:~#
```

Guessing from some testing:

- `ACTIVE`: the HDD did something within a certain timespan (it doesn't seem to mean that it does something right now)
- `NO_ACTIVE`: there was some activity, but in a while it'll be going to standby
- `STANDBY`: well, the HDD is in standby

And to be complete on this `SuspendingTime` is the time in minutes after the HDD should go to standby.

Since I'm no Unix-pro I can't tell if you are supposed to have `/proc/d_suspdtime` on your system, too (guessing from Google results it *may* be related to NAS or busybox).

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have `/proc/d_suspdtime`.

Comment: seems that not normal kernel feature